# Find the general formula of $u_n$:

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find the general formula of $u_n$:
$$\begin{cases}u_1=\frac{5}{4}\\[10pt]u_{n+1}=8u_n^4-8u_n^2+1, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: What sort of class is this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to realize that your polynomial is a [Chebyshev Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). These polynomials have nice properties you can exploit.

Define $P(x) = x^4$, $L(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x + x^{-1})$, and $Q(x) = 8x^4 - 8x^2 + 1$. You can verify directly that $$L\circ P = Q\circ L.$$ Note, moreover, that $5/4 = L(2)$. Then $$u_n = Q^{n-1}(5/4) = Q^{n-1}(L(2)) = L(P^{n-1}(2)) = L(2^{4^{n-1}}) = \frac{1}{2}\left(2^{4^{n-1}} + 2^{-4^{n-1}}\right)$$ for each $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Note also that this agrees with what @dexter04 found with Wolfram.

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%2b1%29%20=%208%2af%28n%29%5E4-8%2af%28n%29%5E2%2b1,%20f%281%29=5/4) gives $u_n = \cosh{(4^{n-1}\log2)}$.